# Theme button text using Angular Material Design

Tags: angular-material

I'd like to use `$mdThemingProvider` to universally configure all buttons on my site with a custom palette. I can manipulate the buttons' background color by configuring `A200` and `A700` in the palette. I would also like to change the default text color. I've jiggered with `contrastDefaultColor`, `contrastLightColors`, and `contrastDarkColors` but the best I've been able to do is get black or white text.

The following snippit will produce white buttons with dark text:

```
var lightGrey = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('grey', {
  'A200': '#fefefe', // Element background color (default)
  'A700': '#fefefe', // Element hover background color (default)
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark',
  'contrastLightColors': '600 700 800 900'
});
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('light-grey', lightGrey);

$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  // Accent palette controls buttons, links, etc
  .accentPalette('light-grey');
```

Changing `contrastDefaultColor` to "light" causes the text to turn white.

I could manually achieve the effect I want by overriding the generated stylesheet's rules:

```
.md-button.md-default-theme.md-fab {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

...but I'm trying to use the tools provided in the library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are facing this problem but by giving A200 & A700 the color you want to give will solve the problem. like this:

```
var lightGrey = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('grey', {
  'A200': '#bdc3c7', // Element background color (default)
  'A700': '#bdc3c7', // Element hover background color (default)
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark',
  'contrastLightColors': ['600', '700', '800', '900']
});
```

**Note**: Try to give contrast palette in array form.

And if you are facing some different problem please update or you can refer this [link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme)

Comment: Wow. This question is old. We've been keeping up with the updates, but for this problem ended up just creating an additional class and haven't revisited since. When I have a cycle I'll give it another go and let you know. Much appreciated.